# Updating record when table is empty - CF hangs

Tags: oracle, coldfusion, oracle10g, sql-update, coldfusion-9

I came across something yesterday that took me a while to figure out. On this code, the server hangs when no records exist in the table being updated, and doesn't give a timeout error or any error for that matter. With records in the second table, the code works fine.

```
<cfquery name="getSomething">
    SELECT one, two
    FROM some_table
    WHERE conditions = 'my conditions'
</cfquery>
<cfloop query="getSomething">
    <cfquery name="updateSomethingElse">
        UPDATE other_table
        SET three = 'my value'
        WHERE four = #getSomething.one#
        AND five = #getSomething.two#
    </cfquery>
    <!--- always run an insert --->
    <cfquery name="insertSomething">
        INSERT INTO other_table
        (columns)
        VALUES
        (values)
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

I'm thinking this is a CF problem because running the update query in Toad does what one would expect when there are no records - nothing.

I fixed it by first running a query to get the count of records in the second table, and only running the update query if the record count is greater than 0.

This is using Oracle 10, CF 9.02 with hotfixes.

Notes: the select query returns between 2K/20K records; 
    the update and insert queries both run correctly when there are existing records in the second table; 
    removing the update query allows the insert queries to run regardless of whether there are records in the second table.

EDIT: I'm going to explore moving both the update and insert queries out of the loop as suggested below. I still don't think the original question (of why the server hangs in the situation of no records in the second table) has yet been answered though.

Comment: _"With records in the table, the code works fine."_ - no it doesn't; you're missing the closing quote on the cfloop's query attribute.

A query loop wont execute its body if there are no records, so there must be more to this than what you've shown here.

Comment: This is just something I typed up to demonstrate the issue. The actual code was correct - and as I mentioned, it ran fine when there were records in the table. Also, the select query returns between 2K and 20K records depending on the params passed int.

Comment: Providing the _actual_ code (with _only_ sensitive/repetitive information sanitized/snipped) always makes things easier and clearer...

Comment: You currently appear to be running the update on every one of those 2-20K loop iterations. If so, move it out of the loop so it runs once, (and ideally do the insert/select combo Matt suggests too).

Answer (score 2):

the server wouldn't hang on the UPDATE if there were no records returned because it would never get to the UPDATE statement. I would recommend removing your UPDATE query and outputting just 'record' in the loop when no records are returned. The server should still hang, so then you can rule out your UPDATE being the issue

But, why not add a check for records?

```
<cfquery name="getSomething">
SELECT one, two
FROM some_table
WHERE conditions = 'my conditions'
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="getSomething">
 <cfif getSomething.RecordCount>
  <cfquery name="updateSomethingElse">
  UPDATE other_table
  SET three = 'my value'
  WHERE conditions = 'other conditions'
  </cfquery>
 </cfif>
 <cfquery>
 INSERT
 </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

I would also recommend using an UPDATE statement that joins the two tables together. If you're hitting your database with 12,000 updates, that's probably taking at least ten minutes when running the code below will take much less time.

```
<cfquery name="updateSomethingElse">
UPDATE other_table
SET three = 'my value'
FROM some_table, other_table
WHERE some_table.id = other_table.id
AND some_table.conditions = 'my conditions'
AND other_table.conditions = 'other conditions'
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="getSomething">
INSERT INTO other_table (one, two)
SELECT one, two
FROM some_table
WHERE conditions = 'my conditions'
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Well, the reason I'm running the loop is that I'm also doing an insert query after the update, which has to happen every time through the loop. Even with 20K records, 20K updates and 20K inserts happen in less than a minute. This is meant to be an administrative function where earlier records get updated (basically made inactive) and new records are inserted simultaneously, and would typically be run only once a year or so by an admin. I will look into your suggestion for the update statement though - that sounds like a possibility.

Comment: i updated my answer to better fit your question. You can also do an INSERT/SELECT statement as well, so you're only running 2 queries no matter how many records are returned

Comment: You can also run a merge so that it inserts or updates since the target table is the same.

Comment: iivel, MERGE is the way to go, as it turns out... it took a little while to figure out the syntax with this query, but man, is that fast compared to the way I was doing it!

Comment: I should have put that in my answer instead of a comment, I'll update for detail tomorrow so that it's available for future searchers. But yeah, merge is an awesome feature.

Answer (score 1):

As for why this is hanging, is a call ever being made to the database or is it hanging when the second query is being evaluated [I'm guessing that you mean the second table is the empty one]. I seem to remember an issue like this that I could only solve using the same method you note, however - a second cfquery isn't strictly necessary since you can use subselects and update on select. If your conditions in the update are generated from the first query, a cartesian product could be created resulting in an excessively long running query (that depending on your timeout settings wouldn't actually timeout).

I'd be interested in the full query since a alternate approach would be to remove the necessity for a loop and let the database do what a database does. Oracle allows an update based on select so you'd have:

```
UPDATE other_table OT
SET OT.three = ( SELECT one 
                 FROM some_table ST
                 INNER JOIN OT
                      ON OT.whatever = ST.stuff
                 WHERE conditions = 'conditions')
WHERE other_conditions = 'other conditions'
```

Given your clarified statement that you require the ability to select from an initial table followed by an update or delete you've got the merge command available to you, the action of the merge is effectively an insert or update (sometimes called an upsert). The Wikipedia link actually is pretty clear on how to structure the syntax.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)